# Can I pass a partial block into the partial I'm rendering in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a modal that I have extracted into a partial in my "shared" folder and will be rendering via a javascript call using a view.js.erb file. I want to render this modal partial, and be able to render another partial block inside of this modal partial, but this needs to be dynamic. I should be able to pass in the partial when I call render on the modal partial. I've tried passing in a local with the partial location, and this will work, but it doesn't really solve cases where I also have locals that I want to pass to the nested partial.

Here's my code below:

The call from my new.js.erb view file (current w/ a local).

```
$('body').append('<%= j(render '/shared/modal', :modal_title => "Create a new Question",      :partial => "render 'questions/form', :btn_message => 'Create'") %>');
```

_modal.html.erb

```
<div class="modal hide" id="modal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3><%= modal_title %></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  </div>
  <%= render partial %>
<!--   <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
  </div> -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't tested, but let me know if it works for you:

```
$('body').append('<%= j(render '/shared/modal', :modal_title => "Create a new Question",      :partial => "render 'questions/form', :partial_vars => {:var1 => 'first var', :var2 => 'second var}, :btn_message => 'Create'") %>');
```

Notice I added the "partial_vars" param and sent it to the partial. Then, in your modal's shared partial have this:

```
<%= render :partial => partial, :locals => partial_vars %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if exactly this can be used in your use case, but it might provide some inspiration:

This is the parent HAML Snippet

```
- render_component :some_params do
  %h2 Titel
  -# whatever you need
```

Within the helper you can pass the block to the partial

```
  # in helper
  def render_component(some_param, &block)
    # do other things
    concat(render :partial => "shared/component", 
                  :locals => {:some_param => some_param,
                              :block => block})
  end
```

And this is the internal partial

```
.someCopmonent
  .title
    = some_param
  .renderPassedBlockhere
    - concat(capture(&block))
```